# prove that this number contains two equal digits

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

We delete the first digit from the number $7^{1996}$ and then we add it to the remaining number, repeat this until we get a number consisting of $10$ digits, prove that, this number contains two equal digits?

any help guys please?

Comment: What is the first rank of a number, and what is a number consisting of $10$ ranks?

Comment: I don't know, maybe I meant digits?

Comment: That would kinda make sense.

Comment: done man, any help?

Comment: Hint: $7^{1996}$ is not divisible by $9$.

Comment: my problem that I heat hints

Comment: @nosa: Then why bother in the first place?

Comment: Two things to check.  First, that this operation conserves some invariant about the number.  Second, that $7^{1996}$ has a different value of this invariant than all $10$-digit numbers with no repeated digits.  @RobertIsrael's suggestion was that you use "is it divisible by 9?" as the invariant.

Comment: @Robert Israel , I really tried but I couldn't

Comment: If I didn't miss anything, any 10-digits number does not contain two equal digit if and only if it contains all the digits $0,1,2,\cdots,9$, and from here you can see that if a number contains all the digits then it must be divisible by $9$ (the sum of its digits is divisible by $9$) but the first operation conserves the divisibility by $9$ so the first number $7^{1996}$ must be divisible by $9$ which gives you the contradiction. This is the shema for the proof, you may write things rigorously ..;

Comment: BTW, the actual $10$-digit number in this case turns out to be $1462965163$.

Answer (score 3):

Robert's hint is superb.

Full solution:
If $k$ is the leftmost digit of $n$ then the number resulting from removing the leftmost digit of $n$ is congruent to $n-k\bmod 9$. Hence if we add $k$ to this number we obtain a number congruent to $n\bmod 9$.

Conclusion: The congruence $\bmod 9$ is invariant under the operation of removing the leftmost digit of $n$ and adding that number to $n$, hence the number that we shall reach will not be a multiple of $9$ (since it wasn't a multiple of $9$ initially). The number has $10$ digits, if it had no digit repeated the sum of the digits would be $0+1+2+\dots+9=45$ and the number would be a multiple of $9$. So there is a repeated digit.